# Extracting strings from javascript functions

Tags: text-processing

I have several html files containing a javascript function like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>eval(function(...............
..............................
781a802d711afb9fe305d5b2e6|nlgphp5ee35huxvkc5xui4xl|gr6weglhvfovda4zodalt7j7glkt5ua|hojehp5ee35huxvkc5xui4xlugr6weglh|vfovl443odalt7klrfbtu4q|mystring123|data|new'.split('|')))
</script>
.......................
<div class="description">mytitle123</div>
```

I'd like to extract the part between the | and |data|new (in this case "mystring123"), and also the title "mytitle123". The first string is always located in an eval and ends with the |data| delimiter, but the alphanumeric strings before it change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML/HTML documents should be processed with a proper parser tools.

**`xmllint`** approach (with `sed` support to search/replace within arbitrary `<script>` tag body text):

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath '//script/text()' input.html | sed -En 's/.*\|([^|]+)\|data\|new.*/\1/p'
mystring123
```

---

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath '//div[@class="description"]/text()' input.html
mytitle123
```

Comment: It works, but apparently the html documents are badly formatted as I get lots of "HTML parser error : End tag : expected >" and "Unexpected end tag" and "Tag footer invalid". The --nowarning option doesn't work. Is there a way to suppress those messages and only get the result (last line in xmllint's output) ?

Comment: redirect errors: `<comand> input.html 2>/dev/null`

Comment: edit: although the 2> redirection doesn't work for some reason, 1>myfile writes the "clean" result to a file, enough for me. thanks!